# Put data to JSON Object in Android 4.4 wrong position

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I have a problem with Android 4.4 when trying to put data to a json object. Here is the code I used to put data to my json:

```
JSONObject jsSimple = new JSONObject();
jsSimple.put("a", "1");
jsSimple.put("b", "2");
jsSimple.put("c", "3");
jsSimple.put("d", "4");
```

And I got the result here:

> { "a":"1" , "c":"3" , "d":"4" , "b":"2" }

This problem only met on Android 4.4. I tested on other version and it work fine. Please give me a direction to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: the order of the keys: **a, c, d, b** and not **a, b, c, d**

Comment: I don't think JSON objects are intended to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use Google `GSON` is easy to use and also it will avoid bugs a code , just define your DTO class some like

```
public class Data {
     private String key;
     private String value;
public Data(String key , String value)
{
this.key = key; 
this.value =value;
}
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }}
```

create your list of object

```
Data data = new Data("a","1"); 
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
dataList.add(data); // so on for all object 
String json = new Gson().toJson(dataList);
```